# How to Find Affine Transform Between Triangles?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, geometry, coordinate

Using Matlab, I'm trying to solve an affine transformation of 6 triangles (see `A` and `Aprime`)...

3 triangles are in `A`

```
triangle1: points 1,2,3 of A 
triangle2: points 4,5,6 of A 
triangle3: points 7,8,9 of A
```

Where X/Y coordinates of A are :
`A.x = [x1 x2 x3; x4 x5 x6; x7 x8 x9]`
 and 
`A.y = [y1 y2 y3; y4 y5 y6; y7 y8 y9]`

And there's also 3 triangles in `Aprim`.

```
triangle5:points 1,2,3 of Aprim 
triangle6:points 4,5,6 of Aprim 
triangle7:points 7,8,9 of Aprim
```

Where X/Y coordinates of Aprim are :
`Aprim.x = [xp1 xp2 xp3; xp4 xp5 xp6; xp7 xp8 xp9]`
 and `Aprim.y = [yp1 yp2 yp3; yp4 yp5 yp6; yp7 yp8 yp9]`

I need to find affine transforms that map each triangle of `A` to triangle of `Aprim` in this way:

- **t1** is affine transform that map triangle1 of A to triangle1 of Aprim.
- **t2** is affine transform that map triangle2 of A to triangle2 of Aprim.
- **t3** is affine transform that map the points triangle3 of A to triangle3
  of Aprim.

**Problem #1** : In my code, **tform** only give me affine transform  t3. I don't know how to change it to know affine transform for t1, t2, t3.
**Problem #2** : My other problem is that in **tform** matrix, which elements are translation,rotation,scaling values? how to find scaling ,rotation angle and translation values?

Can anybody help me to correct my matlab code below? How to solve **t1**, **t2** and **t3**?

My code is :

```
A.x=[309  367  295;273  268 298;295 367 298];            
A.y=[292  259  277;228  253  225;277 259 225];   
Aprim.x=[267  211  265;267  261 295;259  261 211]; 
Aprim.y=[301  222  325;301  270 306;213  112 222];
for  i=1:3
A_xprim(1:3,i)= transpose(Aprim.x(i,1:3));
A_yprim(1:3,i)=transpose(Aprim.y(i,1:3));


Ax(1:3,i)= transpose(A.x(i,1:3));
Ay(1:3,i)=transpose(A.y(i,1:3));

tform = maketform('affine',[A_xprim(1:3,i) A_yprim(1:3,i)],[ Ax(1:3,i)  Ay(1:3,i)]);
end
```

Comment: Do you have a code attempt that others can quickly check for you? If you show what you've tried, you'll get a faster answer.

Comment: I don't use Matlab so I cant help with code. This **[manual page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/performing-general-2-d-spatial-transformations.html#f12-33299)** might help you about that transform matrix question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**#1:** That's because you are trying to store all transformation structs in one variable. Try this:

```
tform(i) = maketform('affine', ...);
```

**#2:** The transformation matrix is stored in `tform(i).data.T`. And [this](http://de.mathworks.com/help/images/performing-general-2-d-spatial-transformations.html) is the documentation about its elements. But in your case the transformation matrix is actually the result of [matrix multiplication of basic affine transforms](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/718935) (translation, rotation, scale and shear). For example we can't say first element shows the value of scale along x-axis or cosine of rotation angle.

The other problem is that you said that you want to *map each triangle of `A` to triangle of `Aprim`*, but the code seem to to do the opposite. I edited your code to test the results:

```
clc; clear; close all;
A.x=[309  367  295;273  268 298;295 367 298];
A.y=[292  259  277;228  253  225;277 259 225];
Aprim.x=[267  211  265;267  261 295;259  261 211];
Aprim.y=[301  222  325;301  270 306;213  112 222];
for  i=1:3
    Axprim(1:3,i)= transpose(Aprim.x(i,1:3));
    Ayprim(1:3,i)=transpose(Aprim.y(i,1:3));

    Ax(1:3,i)= transpose(A.x(i,1:3));
    Ay(1:3,i)=transpose(A.y(i,1:3));

    tform(i) = maketform('affine',[Ax(1:3,i) Ay(1:3,i)],[ Axprim(1:3,i)  Ayprim(1:3,i)]);
end

[X, Y] = meshgrid(260:5:370, 220:5:300);
n = numel(X);
C = ones(n, 3);
[~, I] = sort(X(:)+Y(:));
C(I, 1) = linspace(0, 1, n);
C = hsv2rgb(C);

TX = [A.x A.x(:, 1)];
TY = [A.y A.y(:, 1)];
TPX = [Aprim.x Aprim.x(:, 1)];
TPY = [Aprim.y Aprim.y(:, 1)];

subplot(221); hold on; axis equal;

scatter(X(:), Y(:), 100, C, '.');
plot(TX', TY', 'linewidth', 2); 
plot(TPX', TPY', '--', 'linewidth', 2);
xlabel('X'); ylabel('Y');
for i = 1:3
    subplot(2, 2, i+1);
    axis equal; hold on;
    [U, V] = tformfwd(tform(i), X(:), Y(:));
    scatter(U(:), V(:), 100, C, '.');
    plot(TPX', TPY', 'linewidth', 2);
    xlabel('U'); ylabel('V');
end
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help. I need to calculate scal,rotate angle and translation parameter. because I want to optimize them. can you help me how to find them?

Comment: @jiang you need to ask another question. There are lots of details that should be explained and comment is not right place for that.